# Kotlin Webview cant access dropzone

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, webview

Im trying to access the the dropzone on a Kotlin webview but cant figure out how to  access it.

this is how i declare the webview on  onViewCreated

```
    wvInforme.addJavascriptInterface(WebAppInterface(this@InformeCreateFragment.context!!), "Android")

    wvInforme.loadUrl("https://admin.maxlink.ec/informe.php")
    wvInforme.setWebViewClient(WebViewClient())
    wvInforme.restoreState(savedInstanceState)
    wvInforme.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    wvInforme.settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true)
    wvInforme.settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false)

    wvInforme.settings.allowFileAccess = true
    wvInforme.settings.allowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true
```

[image]

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I'm running into the same problem.